# Asp.Net MVC Forbidden In Plesk

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, web-hosting, plesk

MVC Application Not Working After Hosting
I have purchased Windows hosting from Godaddy to host my ASP.Net MVC application. The site is working well on my local. But after moving to godaddy it gives 403- Forbidden error. This is the URL :

Url: http://www.dhirenpatel.in/

[image]

Kindly suggest whether Godaddy support such code or is it any other issue. If not I will move to some other hosting which supports mvc. The documentation which godaddy provides ha very less details on the same.

Godaddy Customer Support people also dont know much about fixing the issue.Called them and wasted my time.

Nothing helped.

Comment: Maybe **[403 error, Forbidden](https://uk.godaddy.com/community/Managing-Web-Hosting/403-error-Forbidden/m-p/16707#M494)** will help

Comment: This looks like an Apache error screen. Are you positive you're on Windows hosting?

Comment: yes,I deploy on Window hosting(Plesk).I deploy simple MVC scaffolding template on that hosting.

Comment: @lzzy thank you for reply but support team tell me that mvc razor not work on that hosting use aspx instead of .cshtml :)

Comment: Hi, maybe ASP support is not enabled on subscription:   Domains > example.com > Hosting Settings -> Microsoft ASP support ?

Comment: @DhirenPatel How is your issue? From the error message, plesae make sure you setup your default page correctly. You can setup it on the control panel. If you dont know how to do it, just contact your support team.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Get Windows Hosting Plan from Go Daddy to host your Asp.Net related project

Step 2 :

Login to your GoDaddy Account add new temporary domain to test your application

Create a folder to publish your project build

Create new FTP account

If you have database create new SQL Server Database

Step 3:

This step is using FileZilla FTP software, if you want to use Visual Studio FTP then follow steps in [this](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-host-your-Asp-Net-mvc-website-on-godaddy-server/) article.

Publish your project to File System

Download FileZilla Client Using FileZilla FTP login to your GoDaddy FTP account and upload your project files and dll's.

Type your temporary domain name in browser to check your hosted application , if you still get errors you can research and fix it or ask a new question related to your error.

> I Hope You Follow these things already but please kindly check if while uploading time you use visual studio local ftp its might be problem to corrupt some dlls while internet getting down!! So please use FTP filezilla like that. Use this i Hope it helps to solved your problem.

Comment: thank you for answer.I follow samestep but its not work

Comment: Ok!! Can U Check web.confige file after published in plesk panel for  Some Code:  LIke <customErrors mode="Off" />
                   <trust level = "full" /> These Two line, If Not added please add these its working fine, if added already please kindly ignore. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to go in and set the virtual directory default page flag in the hosting for the website.  That worked for me so that it pointed to index.html.